# How to add an out-of-tree package to buildroot?

Tags: buildroot

I am using buildroot to build a custom filesystem for the Raspberry Pi. So far everything works fine, but I can’t manage to add an out-of-tree package. I am trying to add WiringPi, since WiringPi has been marked as legacy in buildroot and is therefore not included anymore.

My external folder structure:

```
./Config.in
./external.desc
./external.mk
./package
./package/Confige
./package/custom_wiringpi
./package/custom_wiringpi/custom_wiringpi.mk
./package/custom_wiringpi/Confige
```

custom_wiringpi/Confige:

```
config BR2_PACKAGE_CUSTOM_WIRINGPI
        bool "custom_wiringpi"
        help
          https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi
```

This seems to work, because I can select wiringpi in `menuconfig`. But it does not get build.
My `custom_wiringpi.mk`:

```
CUSTOM_WIRINGPI_VERSION = 20210904
CUSTOM_WIRINGPI_SOURCE = 7f8fe26e4f775abfced43c07657a353f03ddb2d0.zip
CUSTOM_WIRINGPI_SITE = https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi/archive/

define CUSTOM_WIRINGPI_BUILD_CMDS
        sh build
endef
```

I would expect this to at least download the source and extract it, but make just completely ignores this.
My `external.mk`:

```
include $(sort $(wildcard $(BR2_EXTERNAL_ROOTFS_PATH)/package/*/*.mk))
```

How can I get buildroot to actual execute the build steps I defined?

---

I am aware that similar questions have been asked on SO, but none of them cover my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to include this line in my `custom_wiringpi.mk`:

```
$(eval $(generic-package))
```

Now Make behaves as expected.

Answer (score 2):

`BR2_EXTERNAL_ROOTFS_PATH` is most likely wrong in your external.mk. The BR2_EXTERNAL__PATH must match the name of the BR2_EXTERNAL as defined in your external.desc. Could you share your external.desc ?

See the documentation at https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#outside-br-custom or also the training slides https://bootlin.com/doc/training/buildroot/buildroot-slides.pdf starting slide 250.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Just a few seconds later, I figured out what was going wrong (see my answer). Of course I read the documentation, but it would just be nice if there was a "dummy" example. Anyway, I can work from here.